# one clicked with 2 pop-up window error

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

Does anyone know what is it going on? I wrote the following code, so that the user clicked on the code and it will pop-up a window for another page. Somehow, this is always pop-up 2 windows every time when I clicked on the link.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <a id="goLink" style="cursor:pointer">Link</a>
    </td>
  </tr> 
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#goLink").click(function () {
        window.open("http://localhost/test.aspx");
    });

</script>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: None of this is C# code.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that would happen is when you have wired up two click events unknowingly for the anchor tag `goLink` in your page. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

does your anchor have a href attribute to if that is the case there might be a default click firing and you need to stop that using preventDefault method